# Ways of reducing CPU usage while building JavaScript based web browser

Tags: javascript, webbrowser-control, cpu, ram, mern

I'm trying to develop web browser which includes inbuilt ad-block and inbuilt proxy with minimum CPU usage. This project will be created using MERN and ElectronJS. I want to know what are the ways to develop it to consume less CPU and RAM. Engines going to be used are 'Blink', 'Webkit', 'V8'. And also what are challenges that I may face while developing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CPU Usage will depends upon how many applications you are running right now. It doesn't make any difference with using your browser. and coming to RAM, removing unnecessary functions will make it faster. If your project has any unnecessary functions or extra code, remove them.

And coming to challenges, since you have mentioned Proxy, be through with it.